# R - two-sample_t_test Unchanged When Switching Between Pooled Variance and non-Pooled Variance

Tags: r, statistics

I run the R code as follows:

```
library(oibiostat)
data("swim")
## independent two-sample pooled t test
t.test(swim$wet.suit.velocity, swim$swim.suit.velocity, 
       alternative = "two.sided", paired = FALSE, var.equal = TRUE)

#unequal variance two-sample t test
t.test(swim$wet.suit.velocity, swim$swim.suit.velocity, 
       alternative = "two.sided", paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE)
```

Which results in the same output:

```
    Two Sample t-test

data:  swim$wet.suit.velocity and swim$swim.suit.velocity
t = 1.3688, df = 22, p-value = 0.1849
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.03992124  0.19492124
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 1.506667  1.429167
```

and

```
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  swim$wet.suit.velocity and swim$swim.suit.velocity
t = 1.3688, df = 21.974, p-value = 0.1849
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.03992937  0.19492937
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 1.506667  1.429167
```

The pooled two-sample t.test should be different from un-pooled one in terms of formulas.

But if I run the code as follows:

```
set.seed(5)
x1 = rnorm(15, 95, 20)         
x2 = rnorm(50, 110, 5)
t.test(x1, x2) # Welch
t.test(x1, x2, var.eq=T) # pooled
```

The outputs from both t.test are clearly different. So, I just got a coincidence of data set?

I calculate by hand and find that the output from `Welch Two Sample t-test` is right.  I am very confused why the output of pooled t.test is wrong.

---

## Edit

Like I say in comment, package `oibiostat` is not on CRAN, it's on GitHub. If not installed yet, run

```
devtools::install_github("OI-Biostat/oi_biostat_data")
```

And there's no need to load a package to access one of its data sets, the following will load it.

```
data(swim, package = "oibiostat")
```

Comment: The code for calculation by hand is as follows: ```s_pool=sqrt((11*var(swim$wet.suit.velocity)+11*var(swim$swim.suit.velocity))/22)
s_pool
t_pool=(mean(swim$wet.suit.velocity)-mean(swim$swim.suit.velocity))/s_pool
t_pool

s_unp=sqrt((var(swim$wet.suit.velocity)/12+var(swim$swim.suit.velocity)/12))
t_unpool=(mean(swim$wet.suit.velocity)-mean(swim$swim.suit.velocity))/s_unp
t_unpool```

Comment: Package `oibiostat` is not on CRAN, where can we find it?

Comment: In the pooled test you have `df = 22` and in Welch `df = 21.974`. Maybe you're right and got a coincidence.

Comment: In your manual example, you are creating truly different groups, hence the difference between both tests is visible. In your first data example, you also obviously have differences (see the dfs and confidence intervals), it‘s just that the difference is very small, which indicates that the mean and  variance in both groups are not so different.

Comment: But the two t values shouldn't be the same as 1.3688! Using the formula by hand, the t from pooled is 0.5588067 instead of 1.3688.

Answer (score 0):

You have equal sample sizes in the two groups, n_1=n_2=12. That is important, because in that case the test statistics for the pooled (equal-variance) t-test and the Welch (unequal-variance) r-test are equal in value, as you can verify by consulting the formulas at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test), explaining why you get identical results. (This have been discussed at Cross Validated, but I couldn't find where ... But  see maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/563859/equal-variance-vs-unequal-variance-for-comparing-groups  and search that site).

There **is** one small difference, the degrees of freedom are not equal, but the difference is not large enough to make for a difference in p-values or confidence intervals.

But, by the way, in your `swim` example, the samples are **paired**, so you should really do

```r
with(swim, t.test(wet.suit.velocity, swim.suit.velocity, 
                    alternative = "two.sided", paired = TRUE))

    Paired t-test

data:  wet.suit.velocity and swim.suit.velocity
t = 12.318, df = 11, p-value = 8.885e-08
alternative hypothesis: true mean difference is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.06365244 0.09134756
sample estimates:
mean difference 
         0.0775
```